# Anytime I install flutter or android studio, face challenges with Gradle, mostly if i install freshly it works for first 3 app runs then goes berserk

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, gradle, build.gradle

The Gradle only runs about 3 times when the whole flutter, vscode, is installed newly. same with android studio too. It has slowed down my flutter study and build of my projects. I have tried most approaches on google but still gets that when I run my app

Error message:

[image: image1]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11286032)